# Where did my MSO rep go? -211

Tags: support, status-completed, reputation

I just instantly lost 211 rep on MSO.

A few hours ago I had 1,060, now 849, a 211 decrease.
I don't think I ever received enough votes on one question or answer to lose that much by a single question delete (or whatever).

My profile shows:
9 today
+10 - 7 hours ago - upvote - Notify myself with message and (optionally) a future point in time
-1 - 1 hour ago - downvoted - What questions should NOT be asked on Meta?

Where did it go? Is there somewhere else it could show why it was decreased that I am not aware of?

Ticked the box as Bart suggested, was indeed:
-220 - 1 hour ago - removed - Please, delete this post

Comment: Questions are often summarily deleted on meta. Did this happen to one you had a highly voted answer on perhaps?

Comment: Did you enable "show removed posts" at the bottom of your reputation history?

Comment: @Bart - that was it, thanks! I didn't think I earned that much on one answer. Why was it deleted?

Comment: I would assume that goes together with the deletion of the OP's account

Comment: From the title of the question the OP must have edited it to specifically request the question was deleted though. AFAIK account deletion would just leave it anonymised normally.

Comment: Now refresh your reputation tab and read the title of that removed question.

Comment: The user was deleted. Not sure why.

Comment: @Oded - He was suspended to cool down for 7 days. May be he has deleted himself.

Comment: Looking at the deletion details, it looks like the user requested deletion.

Comment: Thanks all - makes sense. I know this is how it works, but it's a tad annoying losing *answer* rep when someone deletes a *question*. My rep from a good answer and hard work shouldn't be wiped away as if *I never did it*. I remember spending some time on that answer to help the OP, I was even nice! I imagine there are many questions/feature-requests about this already so wont bother :) thanks again for the infos

Comment: ..and thanks for the upvotes here, took the sting out a bit :)

Comment: @James - Lol you have now earned 30+ reputation because you lost 211 reputation for few hours. :)

Comment: And so subtle no-one will ever know I gamed it... mwuhahaa (ok jk, no downvotes..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A user who had three heavily downvoted posts tried to disassociate himself from the three this morning. Initially, he did it by repeatedly vandalizing them to just say "Delete me". Then they were locked and his account suspended for 7 days.

If memory (from this morning) serves, you had an answer on one of those - I can't verify myself, but one of the 10k or mods will probably be able to verify that you had an upvoted answer on this question:

[I've been temporarily suspended. Am I actually a bad user? Should I leave the site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196248/ive-been-temporarily-suspended-am-i-actually-a-bad-user-should-i-leave-the-si)

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.

Comment: Thanks. yeah I actually remember now, >20 votes. I forgot I actually made a decent answer once. Got me the Reversal badge.

Comment: @James I think I upvoted your answer when it was first posted, because I recognized this of the three disputed posts. Can't tell for sure, though. :P

Comment: @James - You still keep the badge but does suck that you lose the 1000 rep privileges for no fault of your own.

Comment: @AndersUP Thanks (well, *if* you did :D ) though you affectively didn't now

Comment: @MartinSmith yeah does suck a bit, but worse things happen at sea... c'est la vie

Comment: Google Cache also verifies the former content of the post (I was curious)

Comment: @James Now that it's undeleted I can say that I actually *did*. :)

Answer (score 7):

Since the answers to [that question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196248/ive-been-temporarily-suspended-am-i-actually-a-bad-user-should-i-leave-the-si) are pretty ok, I've undeleted it. Your rep should be back soon, too.

Comment: ..and it is! My faith in Stack has been restored beyond what it was previously! Seriously tho, thanks :)